# Кроссплатформенный код на HTML

Tags: html, кроссплатформенность

Сейчас есть разные решения для для разных платформ, но в разных решениях используется разные движки, а значит программа будет отображаться по разному. А есть ли универсальное решение для следующих платформ:

1. Windows,
2. Mac OS,
3. Linux,
4. Android,
5. iOS,
6. Windows Phone?

Comment: как запутанно то!... ответом на вопрос является тема вопроса "Кросс платформенный код" )))

Comment: где запутано? мне нужна программка которая преобразует .html в .exe, .deb, .apk и т.д. грубо говоря

Comment: Нет такого. Есть программки, которые эмулируют нативное оконное  приложение, но никак не переводят в него. Все это использует движок как в браузере.

Comment: "Есть программки, которые эмулируют нативное оконное приложение" мне они и нужны 

"использует движок как в браузере." Как в каком браузере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот](http://get.adobe.com/ru/air/) одна из таких прог. По поводу того, какой движок, то скорее всего -webkit-, но это не факт. Можно покопаться в инете и узнать :)

Comment: [Adobe Air](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Air)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Также можно использовать *[RAD Studio 10 Seattle](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio)*

Это тот самый *Delphi* и *Borland C++*